# Como apagar por completo uma ArrayList e uma List

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como destruir o apagar por completo uma `ArrayList` e uma `List` por completo em tempo de execução.

**exemplo:**

```
ArrayList<Elemento> e = new ArrayList();//Elemento e uma classe

for (int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
   e.add(new Elemento());
   e.get(i).texto = "teste";
   e.get(i).texto2 =  "algo";
   e.get(i).numero = i;
}
```

Como destruir `e` por completo ou apaga-lo?

Comment: ...`e.clear()` ?

Comment: Você quer zerar os elementos ou fazer com que todos sumam? O que você entende por destruir, ou por completo ou apagar?

Comment: @bigown que todos sumam , como não tivesse criado.

Comment: Realmente o `.clear()` resolveu o problema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A melhor forma de fazer isso é criar uma nova instância:

```
ArrayList<Elemento> e = new ArrayList(); //Elemento e uma classe
for (int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
   e.add(new Elemento());
   e.get(i).texto = "teste";
   e.get(i).texto2 =  "algo";
   e.get(i).numero = i;
}
e = new ArrayList();
```

O [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear--) pode resolver isso de outra forma e cada um tem seu lugar.

```
ArrayList<Elemento> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add(new Elemento())
ArrayList<Elemento> y = x;
x = new ArrayList<>(); //y permanece com o elemento, afinal x passou ter uma nova instância

ArrayList<Elemento> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add(new Elemento())
ArrayList<Elemento> y = x;
x.clear(); //y não tem mais nada também
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/CleanList.java).

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que criar uma nova instância resolverá seus problemas.

```
e = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: É? Por que? A sua resposta pode até ser correta, mas se você não explicar o motivo em mais detalhes dificilmente ela irá ajudar outra pessoa (e talvez sequer ajudará o AP a aprender com o erro). Não vou votar pra recomendar a exclusão ainda, mas, por favor, edite-a e melhore-a, ok?